# Firestore CollectionGroup query not showing any result

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to make a search activity with firestore. This is my firestore structure.

```
 /Collection/Document/Collection/Document(ID generated by firesotre)
 /Recipes/Food_Recipe/Rice_Recipe/5LlP3SZO27tL9IIlMhD2
```

And here is my java code,

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collectionGroup("Recipes").orderBy("Recipe_name").startAt(InputSearchText).endAt(InputSearchText+"\uf8ff");
 PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPrefetchDistance(2)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(2)
            .setPageSize(3)
            .build();
 FirestorePagingOptions<FoodItems> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<FoodItems>()
            .setQuery(query, config, FoodItems.class)
            .build();
food_items_recycle_adapter = new Food_Items_Recycle_Adapter(options, progressIndicator,this);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(food_items_recycle_adapter);
    food_items_recycle_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    food_items_recycle_adapter.startListening();
```

And this is my single field index,
[image]

This is how i tried to get the result, But it does not show any result.

**Edit**
I want to get the Document which Recipe_name start with InputSearchText

---

**Edit**

```
 2020-09-21 11:59:24.560 26802-26802/com.example.thechef I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 5944 bytes, containing 1 windows, 26 views
2020-09-21 11:59:24.665 26802-26802/com.example.thechef W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
 2020-09-21 11:59:24.689 26802-26802/com.example.thechef E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
 2020-09-21 11:59:27.029 26802-26802/com.example.thechef D/Search_Fragment: onClick: InputSearchText is   badu
 2020-09-21 11:59:27.071 26802-26802/com.example.thechef D/Food_Items_Recycle_Adap: onLoadingStateChanged: loading initial pages
 2020-09-21 11:59:27.284 26802-26802/com.example.thechef D/Food_Items_Recycle_Adap: onLoadingStateChanged: Wholedata loaded
 2020-09-21 11:59:29.937 26802-26807/com.example.thechef I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=111KB, data=98KB
 2020-09-21 11:59:29.937 26802-26807/com.example.thechef I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=111KB, data=98KB
 2020-09-21 11:59:29.937 26802-26807/com.example.thechef I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

This is all I can see in the android studio logcat, when I type a text in inputEditText and press the search button.

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate exactly what you expect the query to return.  You should also write code check the query for errors to make sure nothing went wrong.  If something did go wrong, show the error message.

Comment: It does not show any error message.

Comment: Your code does now show how you're handling the error. You might be doing it wrong, or not at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson , It shows [E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout] this error, I do not understand because, When i tried Collection(Recipes).document("Food_Recipe).Collection("Rice_Recipe) this shows me result, even i got the same error i mentioned above.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited my question again, please could you please check it again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer to this question helps with Firebase experts. Is it not possible to use the Collection group query for different sub-collections. Sub collections name should be the same if you want to use a group query. There was no issue with java code. The problem was a misunderstanding about the Collection group query. [Firebase expert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988536/how-can-i-query-multiple-different-sub-collection-at-ones) / [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Simply, It is not possible to query from root collection. If I'm wrong please edit this answer :)