# How can I query multiple different sub collection at ones?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I am building a recipe app. I am using firebase as my database. Now I want to let the users to find any recipe which I have stored in my recipe Collection.[image]

Each Food_Recipe has different subcollections. I'll explain my issue using an example.
[image]

Now, I want to find the document which Recipe_name == Biriyani.
I could archive my goal easily using this way,

```
  Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Recipes").document("Food_Recipe")
            .collection("Rice_Recipe").orderBy("Recipe_name")
            .startAt(InputSearchText).endAt(InputSearchText +"\uf8ff");
```

But I need to get the same result across the Recipe Collection.
For example, Just imaging, if Powder_Recipe also have a Recipe_name Biriyani, there should be 2 result from different subcollections.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to query several (sub)collections with different names, you will have to use a dedicated query for each of those collections and merge the results.

If you want to avoid that you would need to adapt your data model.

I understand that there are going to be several `Food_Recipe` documents, since you wrote that "Each Food_Recipe has different subcollections".

So, for example, you could have only one `subRecipes` subcollection under each `Food_Recipe` document and, in this subcollection, make the difference between the `powder` and `rice` recipes with a field in the document (e.g. a field named `recipeType`). This way you can use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query all the `subRecipes` subcollections, as follows:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collectionGroup("subRecipes").orderBy("Recipe_name").startAt(InputSearchText).endAt(InputSearchText +"\uf8ff");
```

Note that I called the subcollections `subRecipes`, since you already have a `Recipes` root collection.

---

And if you want to get all the `powder` recipes for the `Food_Recipe` document, you filter on the field value, as follows:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Recipes").document("Food_Recipe").collection("subRecipes").whereEqualTo("recipeType", "powder");
```

---

More concretely, the proposed data model is the following

```
-- Recipes (root collection) 
   -- Food_Recipe_1 (document)
      -- subRecipes (subcollection)
         -- DocID#1 (document)
            - Recipe_Name: Biriyani (field)
            - recipeType: rice (field)             
            - ....  (field)     
         -- DocID#2 (document)
            - Recipe_Name: Peas Pulao (field)
            - recipeType: rice (field)             
            - .... (field)     
         -- DocID#3 (document)
            - Recipe_Name: Powder Recipe (field)
            - recipeType: powder (field)             
            - ....  (field)     
   -- Food_Recipe_2 (document)
      -- subRecipes (subcollection)
         -- DocID#4 (document)
            - Recipe_Name: Another Rice Recipe (field)
            - recipeType: rice (field)             
            - ....  (field)     
         -- DocID#5 (document)
            - Recipe_Name: Another Powder Recipe (field)
            - recipeType: powder (field)             
            - ....  (field)
```

Comment: I used the Collection Group query but it does not show any result :(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misunderstood your question. I'm going to adapt my answer, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: No Problem Renaud Tarnec. Take your time. I'll wait. Thank you very much.

Comment: As I understand, If there are subcollections like Rice_Recipe, Powder_Recipe, and Vegitable_Recipe. I have to create Collections named Food_Recipe for these each Sub Collections. and try the Collection group query?

Comment: I am going to try this and ill let you know :)

Comment: See the update, which details the proposed data model